# Documentation for accessable object properties

Tags: python, documentation

I'm looking at an export script and I see where it extracts the various 3d properties from an object named "me" like these 3 lines:

```
me = bpy.context.object.data #EDIT: This is what "me" is, I think
me_verts = me.vertices[:]
materials = me.materials[:]
faceuv = len(me.uv_textures) > 0
```

Which it goes on to format and write to a file. Where can I find a list of all the things I can access like this? I found the python API but I haven't found this specifically.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- The export and import scripts are indeed an excellent form of documentation.
- There is a [massive amount of documentation](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/contents.html). This includes a quickstart and API overview. More importantly it has a good search box (**warning:** avoid including parenthesis when searching functions).
- Interactively you can use the python console to investigate which properties are available on a given reference. It has a ctrl+space auto-complete (auto reveal).

in the console for instance

```
>>> obj = bpy.context.object   # the current active object
>>> obj = bpy.data.objects['Cube']   # object specified by name
>>> obj.
```

if you type `obj.` and hit ctrl+space you'll see all the attributes of the object at that level. This list is long, and you can scroll the sidebar

[image]

As you state `me = obj.data`, the *me* named variable is just a convention, it could be called whatever, but it's handy to stick to the convention.

`obj.data.<ctrl+space>` looks like

[image]

If you want to see information about the mesh you might do

```
# get coordinates of 1st vertex (index=0)
>>> obj.data.vertices[0].co   

# indices that make up the first polygon in the mesh
>>> obj.data.polygons[0].vertices[:]
```

[image]

Note that the ctrl+space feature will show all attributes starting with the letter v if you do `obj.data.v<ctrl+space>` like this:

[image]

This becomes useful once you get a mental picture of the API, it can speed up navigation big time.

Comment: The ctrl-space thing was immensely helpful, having the exact names will make finding documentation so much easier.