# Books or web resources for blender-python (bpy)

Tags: python, documentation

I want to create 2D or 3D object that is mathematically created (all vertices and faces are generated by python). I heard blender can create objects via Python. I already know Python and would like to find more information specifically about `bpy`.

I assumed blender python API is well documented, **but I can't find good documentation** (For example, look [this page](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_76_1/bpy.data.html) about `bpy.data`. I think there should be more information about `bpy.data.*`). Are there any books about blender python which complement official documentation? I don't have much time to search the web (like a sea) to find the documentation about blender python, and I don't know which web resource is the best except for official website. So mainly I'm finding a book about blender python now.

I'm currently reading:

- The Blender API - Blender 2.49 Scripting

This is the only book I could find. Any other book or web resources are welcome.

Comment: Have a look at this book: http://airplanes3d.net/pydev-000_e.xml

Comment: I find this blog with few samples of python https://docouatzat.com

Answer (score 3):

Around 2009 / 2010 Blender moved on to the `2.5` series and started using a new and very different python API called *bpy*. Unfortunately that 2.49 Book doesn't cover *bpy* and therefore will have little practical usefulness. In the first couple of years after the new 2.5 series *bpy* changed regularly both in big and in small ways.

Such a fluid environment meant publishing hard-copy documentation wasn't very sensible. This lack of books has not been a barrier for learning *bpy*, for a few reasons:

- Blender has a built in Python console (REPL) it lets you print the docstrings of functions and operators. The REPL auto-completes with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>. [See this answer for directions and usage](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/29137/47) and more.
- Blender, and the add-ons it ships with, are open-source. The nature of these add-ons ranges from convenient *mesh editing tools* and *mesh generation tools* to *importers* and *exporters*. These categories cover almost everything you might want to see examples of -- some are short and simple others are extensive.
- [The cookbook](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:2.5/Py/Scripts/Cookbook/Code_snippets) (for UI and bpy) paved the way for many people, and is still a surprisingly useful reference for figuring out how to declare UI.
- Blender's TextEditor has templates for common bpy procedures:
  *TextEditor > Templates > Python > ...*

You mention that you know Python already. My advice to you is to read the source code of a few Mesh creation add-ons available in  `../scripts/addons`. For instance

```
add_mesh_extra_objects
add_mesh_bolt_factory
```

These two add-ons will give a lot of insight into how to write all the boilerplate needed to convert your mathematical concept and code into an operator using `bpy`.

---

#### add_mesh_extra_objects

This add-on even has a selection of mathematical surface generators which seems to be what you are looking for.

[image]
makes this:
[image]
and xyz makes this:
[image]

Comment: Totally agree with zeffii's tips. I started scripting exactly this way, and also by following some nice tuts on CG cookie, especially the now archived (but still freely available and relevant) tuts by Patrik Boelens: https://cgcookie.com/archive/introduction-to-scripting-with-python-in-blender/

Comment: Another great source is the script cookbook (code snippets) page: http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:2.5/Py/Scripts/Cookbook/Code_snippets
And the small blender things blog (that has lots of OSL, but also lots of BPY stuff): http://www.swineworld.org/search/label/Python
I also write about BPY scripting in my blog: https://bioblog3d.wordpress.com/category/python/

Comment: I agree with scripts cookbook, i use it too sometimes so shouldn't omit it either. As for blogs.. they will come up naturally when users search google, but the downside is they can't be updated by anyone other than the author