# Access operator's property with python

Tags: python

Is it possible to access the property of an operator (such as the filepath to the append operator) by python ?

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/29134/documentation-for-accessable-object-properties?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Return values of operators](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18874/return-values-of-operators)

Comment: poor this is not a duplicate of that Question, it's not about the return values but about the values that can be passed to the operator.

Answer (score 6):

Passing properties to an operator, here's a small example (see the *test call* towards the end). This snippet is an elaboration on *TextEditor > Templates > Python > Operator Simple*

```
import bpy


class SomeOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "object.some_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple Object Operator"
    
    property_one: bpy.props.StringProperty(default='state one')
    property_two: bpy.props.StringProperty(default='state two')

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return True

    def execute(self, context):
        print(self.property_one)
        print(self.property_two)
        return {'FINISHED'}


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SomeOperator)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SomeOperator)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

    # test call
    bpy.ops.object.some_operator(property_one='woop_one', property_two='woop_two')
```

if you want to call such an operator from a layout element..

```
# if you want to pass a single property
row.operator('object.some_operator').property_one = 'some_new_value'

# if you want to pass multiple properties
some_op = row.operator('object.some_operator')
some_op.property_one = 'some new value one'
some_op.property_two = 'some new value two'
```

---

#### Autocomplete

If you don't know the name of the properties, then you can use the Python console's autocomplete.

In this example hit ctrl+space after the parenthesis `(` , here you see `lines` is the only property you can set.

[image]

#### Documentation

Another resource is the [current api docs](https://www.blender.org/api/current/) use the search feature, type in for example `bpy.ops.text.scroll` and it will show the signature.

In the case of `WM_OT_append` you should be looking for `bpy.ops.wm.append`.

#### Tooltips

Use the tooltip that appears by default upon hovering of menu items / buttons:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply but i'd like doing the same operation but with operators which i don't know name of the properties as the WM_OT_append operator.

Comment: @pistiwique how did you find the name of `WM_OT_append` ?

Comment: By using the console's autocomplete typing bpy.types.

Comment: OK, then might I suggest using the tooltips that appear when hovering over menu items, that way you'll see the `bpy.ops.*` , when you autocomplete those , you will see the parameters as described above