# Problem with custom button for apply transformations on model

Tags: scripting, interface

want to have button for apply transformations, but when I tried this code, it just doesn't work :(

```
layout.operator("object.transform_apply(location=False, rotation=True, scale=True)"), text="Reset Trasforms")
```

can someone please help me?

Comment: [Related](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/60427/15543)

Answer (score 2):

When adding an operator to a layout, you should only add the API path, e.g. `"object.transform_apply"`. Any parameters can be configured after if you store `layout.operator` in a variable:

```
operator = layout.operator("object.transform_apply", text="Reset Transforms")
operator.location = False
operator.rotation = True
operator.scale = True
```