# How can I modify multiple properties of an Operator in a Panel?

Tags: python, operator, panel

I have an operator that has properties like below

```
class WM_OT_SceneOpen(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "wm.sceneopen"
    bl_label = "Scene Open"

    f_path=StringProperty(default="")
    mybool=BoolProperty(default=True)

    def execute(self,context):
        #some stuff
```

Now I call this in a panel like this and works

```
layout.operator("wm.sceneopen").f_path=str(file)
```

However I also want to be able to pass/modify the `mybool` property as well during the panel execution but I cant find a way to do that.

This must be possible. But how?

Thanks

Comment: This has been asked before, searching for dupes gets harder.. anyway in layout code  `op = layout.operator("foo.bar")` can then use `op.x = 2` followed by `op.name = "foo"` for each property.

Comment: Cheers Possible duplicate of [Access operator's property with python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/60422/access-operators-property-with-python)